How much energy per second would a nuclear reactor need to power a fighter jet?
Fighter jets typically require high amounts of thrust compared to other aircraft. Lets take the F-22 for example, and lets assume the F-22 powered by a nuclear reactor and the F-22 powered by a traditional engine both weigh the same, as in reactor shielding is not a factor. How much power would a nuclear reactor (fusion or fission) need to compress & heat up the air to produce the same amount of thrust as a normal F-22 engine?

A jet engine would need a certain amount of energy per second - called the power - regardless of how that power is produced. That it is produced as nuclear power does not change how much is needed per second. So you might need to clarify exactly what you are asking to? Maybe you are asking whether it is even possible to run a jet engine using nuclear power? If so, then the Engineering SE site might be a better place to ask this in order to get some good application insights.

An F-22 with a nuclear reactor bolted on would take a lot more power to get airborne.

Nuclear reactors can give lots of power, much more power than jet engines, but then they are much too heavier (and if man-controlled, they need heavy shielding), and it turns out it doesn't make lots of sense for a manned fighter jet. Maybe for some kind of monster drone.

The total thermal power output of a jet engine used in a fighter jet is probably on the order of 50MW. This can be estimated by fuel consumption (6000l/h) and energy density of the fuel (35MJ/l). This is without afterburner, I believe. A nuclear reactor with that kind of power output would be rather small-ish (as in 100kg of nuclear and structural materials). The engineering difficulty is probably in the heat exchanger. And, no, a pilot could not survive the neutron flux of such a reactor and it would be impossible to shield as far as I know.

Thank you this helps. Another way i have been going about trying to find this out is by looking at big commercial jet engines with similar thrust to the f-22 and finding their published power output.

@JánLalinský I like the sci-fi imagery of a monster nuclear flying drone.


lets assume the F-22 powered by a nuclear reactor and the F-22 powered
by a traditional engine both weigh the same

On average, the F-22 burns 5,600 liters of fuel per hour, at least according to the first number I found online. If this is correct, given the conversion of 33 MJ per l, then the energy output is ~185 GJ per hour, or 50 MJ/s, also known as 50 MW.
This number is quite similar to the published power of a 777, which is 46 MW, so at least we're on the right order of magnitude.
So that means you would need what would be considered a very small nuclear reactor, or vSMR in the lingo. A small nuclear reactor, or SMR, is anything under 300 MW in most definitions, a vSMR is somewhat less well defined but generally around the 50 mark.
We need to note that's average, so most of that would be cruise power when you might be flying at 60 to 70% thrust, and then there are the afterburners on top which give you another 50% when you need it. So we might estimate the total power needed to be on the order of 150 MW to provide enough energy during combat.
This great difference in power for normal vs combat is why most nuclear powered aircraft designs used the reactor only for cruise thrust, and then used jet fuel for takeoff and combat. The weight and complexity of an afterburner, which would work just as well on a nuclear engine, is tiny compared to the weight of a reactor and the associated plumbing needed for three times as much peak power. However, by burning it only for short times the amount of fuel was low so the weight of the fuel didn't offset the weight of a larger reactor.

Nuclear ramjets are a (theorized) thing - using an unshielded nuclear reactor to directly heat incoming air and expel the superheated air as exhaust - but the reactor needs to output exactly as much power as a jet engine of equivalent quality would have to. The reactor would need to heat the air by just as much as the regular engine would, which means roughly the same power requirement.
The other assumption that I'm implicitly making is that the NR engine weighs just as much as the regular engine. If it weighs less, it will need less power output; if weighs more, which it probably does, it will require more power output.
The reason the idea of a nuclear ramjet is attractive is because there's no fuel involved - in fact, there's not even an oxidizing atmosphere involved. You could run a nuclear ramjet on Earth, or on Titan, or in Jupiter's atmosphere, or anywhere, without even carrying fuel with you - assuming that the engine's nuclear fuel doesn't deplete itself. But the energy density of fissile isotopes is much higher than gasoline, so you get many more newton-seconds of impulse per unit fuel (in other words, the specific impulse of the engine is higher).

I believe the Russians claim to have a working weapon of this type.

They have a similar weapon, as far as I know - a supersonic combustion ramjet ("scramjet")-based hypersonic missile. I don't think it uses a nuclear reactor to heat the incoming air, just regular chemical reactions, but the two designs are functionally very similar.

Yes these are the assumptions i am making too

Using nuclear power to power a nuclear missile, sort of makes sense. Shielding only required for the missile silo.

@KDP Nuclear bombs usually don't have cooling/heat exchanging/turbines/emergency shutdown/monitoring system like reactors must in order to operate. Bombs also need something to compress or impact the fissile material which would get in the way of all of the materials for a reactor. A missile powered with a nuclear ramjet could easily be used tactically to scatter highly-radioactive fissile material over a battlefield, though that constitutes a radiological weapon (which I suppose isn't much better than a nuclear weapon).

How can a nuclear reactor run without fuel? That doesn't make sense!

@PM2Ring I should have clarified - the reactor requires fuel, but the ramjet requires no jet fuel. The fuel is the nuclear fuel, which is many many orders of magnitude more efficient than jet fuel. A nuclear fuel "tank" would be tiny compared to a jet fuel tank and would deliver the same energy/power over the same period of time. NR designs are cool because the reactor could last many years without needing to refuel if properly designed, whereas an equivalent jet engine would need to refuel every few hours.

Ok. The term for that is propellant, "a mass that is expelled or expanded in such a way as to create a thrust or another motive force in accordance with Newton's third law of motion, and "propel" a vehicle, projectile, or fluid payload".

@PM2Ring In this case the propellant would actually be the surrounding atmosphere, since that's what's getting heated up and ejected at speed from the NR nozzle.

Right. Whereas in a standard jet engine the propellant is mostly air, plus the products of burning the fuel (mostly CO2 & water, various nitrogen oxides, and some unburned kerosene).

Yes, we agree. Minor piece of unclarity on my part, thank you for correcting it.
